# losing styles and javascripts on tabs content jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-load

I have [this problem here](http://jsfiddle.net/c_fiddler/92Gbz/7/). When I load the content of a div inside my tab, I lose the styles that was associated with that content. As you can see, initially, the paragraph inside my #content div is green, but after I load new content by clicking on Tab 1 or Tab 2 or Tab 3, I lose the styles that I have defined in my stylesheet saying that:

```
#content p
{
    color: green;
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: we need to see all the HTML that goes along with this.

Comment: @DA. it is all in the fiddle.

Comment: durrr...completely missed the link! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `Tabs` are **not** contained within `#content`

And only `#content p` should be green

Comment: I don't wanna add the Tabs inside my div content, I only want the content paragraph inside my DIV content and YES, as I specified in my stylesheet, only `#content p` should be green

Comment: @user765368 ok... so what is the issue?

Comment: If I load the tabs inside my div content, I'm going to have tabs inside tabs, this is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle example, the css selector for #content p doesn't apply to the content inside the tabs, so the tabs don't have that style. Make a css rule that applies to the content within the tabs that you want to style. Use Chrome developer tool (F12) or Firefox Firebug plugin to inspect the items to you want to style.